# Admob starts to serve its own rewarded videos

Tags: android, video, admob, rewardedvideoad

Recently I've received following mail from admob:
Engage users with rewarded video and maximize the value of content

> At GDC this week, we launched Google’s video advertising demand from AdWords, making it accessible to all AdMob developers.
>   Now with AdMob rewarded mediation, you will have access to Google demand in addition to select 3rd party sources, opening to a wider range of monetization options. If you’re already on AdMob rewarded mediation, AdMob rewarded video ads has by default, been enabled in your account.

We have 3 networks in our admob mediator.Each network has its own serverside callback which notifies our server to credit user after he watched an ad.After these google's updates our app receives only video ads from google which prevents other networks from showing their ads.Unfortunately ads from google don't work as there is no server callback configured for them and I see no such option in the admob dashboard.Its almost imposible to get support from google.
Does anyone know how can I disable or configure these admob videos?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I wonder why they did not implement the server callback before releasing their own video ads.

Comment: exactly.Moreover as google guy says you can't turn this shity feature off.I've decided to consider alternative mediators.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution if you want to get a callback on admob videos. I used [developers.ironsrc.com](http://developers.ironsrc.com/android/sdk-integration/mediation-networks-android/#step-1)'s mediator to serve admob ads they also support other major networks just check out the list on the link. Their SDK supports server to server callback and the callback also gets fired for other mediated networks. The only thing is you are also going to have to show their video ads since you wont be able to disable them.

Comment: Did you manage to get REWARDED video from admob via iron source?I've already switched to heyzap mediation it works quite stable and also supports admob,but there is no rewarded videos from admob.Supported formats for admob are: intaerstitial,video,native,banner.Note video is not rewarded.Unfortunately none of these formats are working  so I decided to exclude admob from the list.

Comment: Yes. Rewarded videos and insterstitial ads can be mediated.